# How to assign same name Class variable in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to assign my context in constructor but when I use "this" ide warn me.  How can I write code like this Java code below, but in Kotlin:

here is java code

```
public class LoginApiService {
    Context context;

    public LoginApiService(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

here is what I want to do

```
class YLAService {


var context:Context?=null

class YLAService constructor(context: Context) {
    this.context=context
}
```

}

Comment: Warn you with what warning?

Comment: it isn't clear what you are trying to do, you should show the Kotlin code so we can see the final intent.  And any warning/error you are having.

Comment: @JaysonMinard you are right, I editted my question

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin, if you provide a `var` or `val` in the constructor, it automatically becomes available as a property you can use. No other assignment is required.

```
class LoginApiService(val context: Context) {

   // Example...
   fun doSomething() {
      context.doSomethingOnContext()
   }
}
```

Comment: you could provide an example with constructor keyword

Comment: using the constructor keyword for no reason is not idiomatic, what @todd presented is typical code.

Comment: I edit my question and I need to write something inside my constructor.